# Spell drain value incorporating net hits or not?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr4

At page 185 of the Shadowrun 20th anniversary rulebook, the example goes like this

> [...]The Drain Code for the Powerbolt is (F ÷ 2) + 1, plus 3 from
>   the net hits, so Raze must resist 6 DV [...]

But at page 203 the Drain value chapter goes

> [...]Drain is based on
>   the spell’s Force; the more powerful the spell, the more exhausting it is
>   to cast. Drain is variable, based on the spell’s Force ÷ 2, rounded down,
>   and modified by Drain modifiers appropriate to each spell. Drain is
>   Stun damage, unless the spell is overcast [...]. Note that
>   no Drain Value can ever be less than 1.

Never mentions net hits

Furthermore, just above that chapter, a notice to make drain more streamlined goes

> [...]For example, a player who has a mage with Magic 5 can assume that she
>   always casts her Acid Stream spell at Force 5, and so she writes the Drain down as DV 5 (based on Acid Stream’s Drain formula for Force 5). If she decides to cast the spell at Force 3 instead, the Drain is modified to DV 4 (base DV 5 minus 1 per 2 points of Force reduction). If she decides to cast it at Force 7, her DV would be 6 (+1 per 2 points)—and the Drain would be Physical as the Force exceeds her Magic.

**TL;DR:**
Should the net hits be applied to drain or not? 
When should it? always/only combat spells/only mana spells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was probably a bad idea for them to use a Direct Combat spell in the early Drain example, because Direct Combat Spells are slightly different from other spells; the section you want starts on SR4A p. 203 with the actual relevant part on the following page.

> Direct Combat spells involve channeling mana directly into a
>   target as destructive and damaging energies rather than generating a
>   damaging effect. Affecting the target’s being on this fundamental level
>   with raw mana requires more focus and more power than producing
>   basic effects; as a result **every net hit used to increase the damage value
>   of a Direct Combat spell also increases the Drain DV of the spell by +1.**

Primarily, this is for game balance reasons - characters do not get a chance to evade a Direct Combat Spell. They either resist the damage, or eat the damage - there's only one test involved.

With an Indirect Combat Spell (the next section), they get two tests - an evasion with Reaction, then a standard Damage Resistance Test (with half Impact armor).

Comment: oh, i see... i had not noticed the first example was a direct spell.
so basically, you NEVER add the net hits to drain except for those ... like...  3 direct combat spells?

Comment: Pretty much. They're exceptionally draining because they're exceptionally nasty.